# Dynamic Separator in ListView

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I want to parse json into list view.

```
{
"Submenus": [
    {
        "MenuName": "Pizza",
        "SubMenu": [
            "Pizza Margherita ",
            "Pizza al Prosciutto",
            "Pizza al Peperoncino "
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuName": "Bøffer",
        "SubMenu": [
            "Oksekødmørbrad"
        ]
    },
    {
        "MenuName": "Dessert",
        "SubMenu": [
            "Chokolade kage"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My class is as follows.

```
public class MenuTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // Getting JSON String from URL..............
        JSONObject jsonObject = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                "http://smartaway.dk/json/submenu.php?resid=" + res_id,
                "POST", params);
        try {
            bestdeal = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_MENU);

            // / LOOping through AllEvents........
            for (int i = 0; i < bestdeal.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e = bestdeal.getJSONObject(i);
                String resname = e.getString(TAG_MENUNAME);
                String city_state = e.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                // Creating New HAsh Map.........
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                // map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_MENUNAME, resname);
                map.put(TAG_PRICE, city_state);
                /*
                 * map.put(TAG_STREET, street); map.put(TAG_COUSINE,
                 * cousine); map.put(TAG_RES_LOGO, reslogo);
                 */
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                bestdeal_list.add(map);
            }
            // }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                MenuAdapter menuAdapter=new MenuAdapter(RestaurantDetails.this.getParent(),bestdeal_list);
                //setListAdapter(menuAdapter);
                list.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

            }
        });
    }
    // }
}
```

Custom Adapter class is as follows.

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MenuAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, null);

    TextView menuname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); // title
    TextView price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    HashMap<String, String> events = new HashMap<String, String>();
    events = data.get(position);
    String menustr = events.get(RestaurantDetails.TAG_MENUNAME);
    String pricestr = events.get(RestaurantDetails.TAG_PRICE);
    menuname.setText(menustr);
    price.setText(pricestr);
    return vi;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}

 }
```

I just want to separate the listview from Menuname. Each Menuname should appear on some textview with background then its respective submenus must be shown under that, then another mainmenu and so on. Please suggest how to implement that and how to modify adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want to do is to use a custom adapter, most likely derived from [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). You will need to override [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and return the number of different kinds of list items that you have in the list. In your case it's 2 since you have menu names and normal list items.

You will also have to override [getItemViewType(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) and return either a 0 if the item at the specified position is a normal list item or a 1 if it's a menu name.

Finally you'll also have to override [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) and return a list item of the appropriate type (menu name or normal list item), based on getItemViewType().

There should be several snippets of code that already does this if you Google a bit. I wrote a [SectionedAdapter](https://github.com/britzl/androidutils/blob/master/src/se/springworks/android/utils/view/SectionedAdapter.java) that does this as well. It's a generic class and it handles sections/heading of a certain type (can be String or some specific class such as Section, Header or MenuName) and section contents as another type. Subclass it and implement the getSectionView() and getItemView(). Add sections and items using addSection() and addItem().